# Golang oci8: error adding symbols: File in wrong format

Tags: oracle, go, oracle11g, oracle-call-interface, oci8

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database in Go using [this package](https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8). I have both server and instantclient installed for both Oracle 11.2 and 12.1, and I'm following the instructions regarding the oci8.pc file. My operating system is Windows.

However, when I run "go get github.com/mattn/go-oci8" (or attempt to install a program that uses the package after having gotten the package's source code directly) I get this error:

```
# github.com/mattn/go-oci8
C:/oraclexe/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server/oci/lib/MSVC/oci.lib: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you done installation exactly like in the README ? https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8 It says the following `You need to put oci8.pc like into your $PKG_CONFIG_PATH. oci8.pc should be like below. This is an example for windows.`

Comment: I copied the sample file contents into my file and made the following changes:
1) The "includedir" field uses the "include" directory twice, so I removed one. Otherwise, it matched up with how my oracle directory is setup.
2) I added a line containing "Version: 11.2" after the "Description" line, since I was getting an error that indicated I needed such a line.
3) I was unsure of what to put in the first line ("prefix"), so I just put "/bmc" in that field.
Otherwise it was exactly the same. And I did put its directory path in the PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable.

Comment: Are you mixing 32-bit and 64-bit? Everything needs to match.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to be the same issue I had trying to install oci8. Are you using TDM_GCC? The problem for me was that TDM_GCC has a compiler / linker bug that prevents from compiling certain files. I used ming64 instead and it worked. You can see my detailed posts regarding that here:

https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8/issues/75